# Pyspark DataFrame : How to map array elements to columns and format string with values

Tags: arrays, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, format-string

I have a Pyspark DataFrame looking like this :

```
sdf1 = sc.parallelize([["toto", "tata", ["table", "column"], "SELECT {1} FROM {0}"], "titi", "tutu", ["table", "column"], "SELECT {1} FROM {0}"]]).toDF(["table", "column", "parameters", "statement"])

+-----+------+---------------+-------------------+
|table|column|     parameters|          statement|
+-----+------+---------------+-------------------+
| toto|  tata|[table, column]|SELECT {1} FROM {0}|
| titi|  tutu|[table, column]|SELECT {1} FROM {0}|
+-----+------+---------------+-------------------+
```

And I try to map the array "parameters" elements to columns, to finally format "statement" with values from columns.

This is what I expect after processing transformation :

```
sdf2 = sc.parallelize([["toto", "tata", ["table", "column"], "SELECT {1} FROM {0}", "SELECT tata FROM toto"],["titi", "tutu", ["table", "column"], "SELECT {1} FROM {0}", "SELECT tutu FROM titi"]]).toDF(["table", "column", "parameters", "statement", "result"])

+-----+------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|table|column|     parameters|          statement|               result|
+-----+------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| toto|  tata|[table, column]|SELECT {1} FROM {0}|SELECT tata FROM toto|
| titi|  tutu|[table, column]|SELECT {1} FROM {0}|SELECT tutu FROM titi|
+-----+------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach with RDD.

```py
def addParamsToQuery(param_ls, query, r):
    new_param_ls = [r[k] for k in param_ls]
    new_query = query.format(*new_param_ls)
    return new_query

columns = data_sdf.columns

data_sdf. \
    rdd. \
    map(lambda r: [r[c] for c in columns] + [addParamsToQuery(r.parameters, r.statement, r)]). \
    toDF(columns + ['result']). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----+------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
# |table|column|parameters     |statement          |result               |
# +-----+------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
# |toto |tata  |[table, column]|SELECT {1} FROM {0}|SELECT tata FROM toto|
# |titi |tutu  |[table, column]|SELECT {1} FROM {0}|SELECT tutu FROM titi|
# +-----+------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

The function `addParamsToQuery` creates the list of parameter values using the column values and inserts into the statement using `.format()`.